# How do you change the pose of an armature without deforming it?

Tags: modeling, armature

I am ripping some models from a game. The models from the game already have bones, mesh, and the armature already applied. There is animations in the game that have the poses that I want, which are saved as .smd files. However when I import the .smd file the pose is all distorted. And when I copy the coordinates of the bones in the .smd file to the model it becomes all distorted. There is so many vertices that manually removing all of them from each mesh would take way too long.

Also when the .smd file is imported it creates its own skeleton and bones. Is there anyway to make the original model take the shape of that?

Is there any way to fix this? If so how do you fix the pose?

This is what the default pose looks like:

[image: Default pose]

However, this is what she should look like:

[image: Wanted pose]

**Update:**

Here is a blend file for the model.
[image]

[Here is a link to the .smd file](https://mega.nz/#!ENlGiBjY!XAVTctYtCvFarvS3UW4c8ZXhVfLDwCFR3iMgVWWKe1A)

Comment: Could you please add screenshots of the problems and also provide both a .blend file and .smd file to be able to help you?

Comment: @Tak :  I have updated the post with a blend file and a link to the .smd file (wasn't sure where else to put it, since the blend-exchange site doesn't allow anything other than blender files). I am not sure what you mean by screenshots of the problems, since the only thing that happens is it gets all distorted (such as her legs are up in the air, her arms are at the bottom and to the side, and her head is way off to the side).